# Word VBA: How to know if the actual save operation is completed?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I am having a problem with the `Document.SaveAs` method in Word VBA with large Word documents, it seems that the save operation is asynchronous, ie. after calling `.SaveAs` it returns immediately,  but with large Word documents the **actual** save operation may not has been completed and it's in progress in another thread.

So what I want to ask is that if there is a way to detect if the **actual** save operation is in progress or finished?

I use Delphi to call the automation interface of Word, if it means something in discussing this problem, but I don't think so?

Comment: Hi all,

It seems that the problem I have is to related to the SaveAs method or the Saved property ,but after calling Range.InsertFile(aFileName), aFileName will be unlocked and you don't know when will it be unlocked...

Comment: That doesn't have to do with your original question though. Maybe you could change your question so that it matches to why you accepted the other answer belowl

Comment: @Otaku,
Thank you for your help. You suggested to inspect the Saved property, but it will not work, according to my experience, and as StevenzNPaul's answer explained, the Saved property will become TRUE even the *actual* saving work is not done yet.

And StevenzNPaul's answer explained it's not possible to "know if the actual save operation is completed" so I accepted his answer. I hope this is clear now. Thank you all the same!

Comment: I'm still not sure how that still has to do with InsertFile.

Comment: do have a look at this thread - it will tell you how to make the Save method synchronous - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/44a82171-a14e-4a9a-9843-ecf747981e75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saveas of the office automation is a out of process call, so it will always run on a seperate process, hence its asynchronous in nature.

There is literally no way to catch the notification unless it gives an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's:

```
If ActiveDocument.Saved = True then
/* 'do something */
End If
```

If the document has not had a `.SaveAs` applied against it before, you can check this the `.Path` as well (i.e. `If ActiveDocument.Path <> "" Then ....`)

Note that it is the Background Save that is asynchronous, not the Save which you invoke manually - that is checked by `.Saved`.